# Where is "The Tenacious Tentacled Terror" used?

Tags: shantae-pirates-curse

I remembering hearing [The Tenacious Tentacled Terror](https://virt.bandcamp.com/track/the-tenacious-tentacled-terror) at some time during the game, but that might just be listening to the OST.

I know it's not Squid Baron's boss theme, since that's "Yo, Go Crazy!", so where have I heard it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That music is used in the "Ye Royal Sewers" area.
Which coincidentally you will indeed access just after talking to Squid Baron since he is standing directly on the titular sewer entrance...

You can check this linked [let's play Youtube video](https://youtu.be/p6XXqfU2nHg?t=167) for a more direct confirmation. Sorry for the quality but it was the best I could find.